# Issue with writing CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl

I am reading and XLSX file. and looping over the rows and colums to remove all the clutter from the excel.

```
    with open("../Converted/test.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header) # write the header        
               
        for i in range(10, max_row + 1):
            full_data_row = ""
            for j in range(1, max_col + 1):
                cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = j)
                if cell_obj.value is not None:
                    full_data_row += str(cell_obj.value) + ','

            full_data_row = full_data_row[:-1]
            writer.writerow(full_data_row)
```

When I print full_data_row it prints the string with , so that is correct.
When i check my csv file. I get this as an ouput:

header1,header2,header3
O,p,z,e,t, ,h,o,s,t,e,d,

Comment: Try putting  `[]` into `writer.writerow` like: `writer.writerow([full_data_row])`

Comment: @Fourier This approach is not recommended as it practically skips row formatting done by the `csvwriter` object.

Comment: tried this. but the below answer was more suiting for my case. thanks anyway for the input man ! much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvwriter.writerow()` expects an iterable (e.g. a list), and will handle the formatting (placing commas between values) for you. Therefore, it parses your string as a list (of characters), printing commas between every character.

An alternative approach could be:

```
for i in range(10, max_row + 1):
    full_data_row = []
    for j in range(1, max_col + 1):
        cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = j)
        if cell_obj.value is not None:
            full_data_row.append(str(cell_obj.value))

    writer.writerow(full_data_row)
```

Comment: This is the right solution ! thanks ! and i am again some wiser on CSV :)